# How to read specific file if it was moved

Tags: java, c++, file, file-io

I'm planning one little project just for fun, so I don't know if I'll use C++ or JAVA yet. So I'm asking info for both of these languages.

Now I'll describe situation, what is possible to happen.
Lets say I have file `C:\Users\T3\My Documents\Downloads\My file.txt`. Doing program flow I save this directory and use it to get that file content. But user may move that file into other directory, let it be `C:\Users\T3\My Documents\Files\My file.txt`. Now if I use previous directory I won't reach that file. But as I know file stays at the same place in disk, lets call it `0x1234567890`. Moving file just changes some data in file system NFTF/ext4/... or some.

There would be one or two problematic situations:

1. If file was moved to other disk. It is impossible to reach it.
2. If file was moved to other partition of the same disk. Not sure if in this possible to reach it but it might be.

My question is how to get that address at disk (I called it `0x1234567890`) and how to read data from file knowing that address.

Comment: You can only open a file given a path using standard filesystem API. Recovery tools work at a lower-level.

Comment: Can you not lock the file while you use it until you finish ?

Comment: @Prix I cannot lock file because user may change file directory not in program flow.

Comment: Thats the job of kernel, to keep addresses. It only let you access files using the function it provides.

Comment: But if you lock the file, it *can't* be moved, until you unlock it. I think that's the point Prix was trying to make.

Comment: @user2246674 I know it is possible to do because music players have this feature. So I need this anyway, whether it works on lower-level or not.

Comment: As a hint, **never** hard-code paths in your program. Always allow paths and file-names to be configurable, if not at runtime then at least pass the paths as parameters to your programs, or store them in a configuration file (or the registry on Windows).

Comment: It probably works for other programs, because once you open the file (and *keep* it open) the file can move around the disk without any problem, you will still read/write the correct file. It's when you *close* the file and try to reopen it that you will have a problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't think, that file locking is a good option, because I sometimes move files from one directory to another, so I think other people also do the same. What is more I didn't said, I hard-code paths, it is set on run-time. These paths is something like a playlist.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg. Keep it open??? It is not so good idea. As I said, it something like a playlist, so it's media files. Keeping it open wouldn't allow other programs to reach it. What is more, if user turns off my program, that file becomes movable.

Comment: Then I reiterate: Do not hardcode paths!

Comment: @ST3 Music players *don't* work like this. They may be able to *rescan* the filesystem (or relevant paths) and *associate files* (e.g. hashing or tags) or might even use [Distributed Link Tracking](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312403) (although I've never seen it used as such myself), but these music players do *not* do any magic with "physical file location" (the closest concept I know of something like "inode number", which still require a scan to find the relevant path). The application-level files access is ***always confined to opening a file by path*** - wherever that comes from.

Comment: @user2246674 Actually, I'm not sure how this works, so asking here. But, anyway I think that there should be some way to get that location because filesystem scanning takes long time, but music players found data quickly, if location was changed.

Comment: @ST3 That's not how it's done. Programs that support "Libraries" no doubt are optimized for this task (and there are a few optimizations that can be made, sure), but there is no magic "physical file pointer" (as I've hinted at, some implementation details like inode numbers may be exposed at a lower level - but this is not available in general nor is it reliable). Try to move one of your media files into a system folder, for instance. If it's detected, I'd really like to know by which player(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will talk from java perspective.
Java does memory management on its own and never exposes them, so you wont get api to fetch memory address of a file.

Although there is a way to write at particular memory address and then access data from that address using `sun.misc.Unsafe` class. It is explain in this post : http://robaustin.wikidot.com/how-to-write-to-direct-memory-locations-in-java

So to summarise , your approach of fetching data from memory address will lead to trouble. You should rather chage your logic and look to lock the file or place file paths at some centralized location which will store modified path as well.

Comment: After reading that article, found out, what it is not offered to do that. Have you ever tried it and what can happen doing it? Also, either I misunderstand that, either there isn't described way to **read** from memory.

Comment: Generally these classes are meant for experimenting and understanding purpose as java doesn't document them and can change or remove them as and when they want. Nothing is guranteed about them as they are not meant for general purpose use.